# SQL: CASE in JOIN table

Tags: sql, join, case

**We have**: 3 tables

- users {id, role_id}
- staff {user_id}
- clients {user_id}

Relation *one-to-one* — users-staff and users-clients

**Sample data**:

[users_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd8hR.png), [client_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVGFI.png)

**Question:** How to select data from these 3 tables optionally?
If *users.role_id = 4* join from *clients*, else join from *staff*. Can i do like something like this?

**I try**:

```
SELECT "users" JOIN CASE WHEN users.role_id IN (4) THEN 'clients' ELSE 'staff' ON "users"."role_id" IN (4) THEN 'clients' ELSE 'staff'.user_id = users.id
```

But have error

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "JOIN" LINE 2: JOIN CASE WHEN users.role_id IN (4) THEN 'clients' ELSE 'sta...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff edit post with sample data pictures for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two queries and then use `UNION ALL` to combine the result:

```
SELECT
    <columns>
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN clients AS c
    ON c.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.role_id = 4

UNION ALL

SELECT
    <columns>
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN staff AS s
    ON s.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.role_id <> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT u.*,
       (CASE WHEN users.role_id IN (4) THEN 'clients' ELSE 'staff' END) as role
FROM users u
WHERE u."role_id" IN (4);
```

The above works.  But if your tables have other columns, you might want:

```
select u.*,
       (case when c.user_id is not null then 'client' else 'staff' end)
from users u left join
     clients c
     on u.role_id = 4 and c.user_id = u.id left join
     staff s
     on u.role_id <> 4 and s.user_id = u.id;
```